# Emulate annnotation inheritance with @AspectJ code style

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

As you know with AspectJ 5 you can write aspects inside *.java files. I.e.:
`public aspect Aspects {}` now can be written as following: `@Aspect public class Aspects {}`.

*Is there any way to write the code below inside Java file? Code:*

```java
public aspect AnnotationInheritor { 
    declare @method : void ItemRepository+.getById(..) : @MyAnnotation;
}
```

P.S. I found `@DeclareAnnotation` that appears at version 1.5.3, but looks like it haven't been implemented yet.

```java
@DeclareAnnotation("void ItemRepository+.getById(..)")
@MyAnnotation void inEmptyListMethod() {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not way as of today. Even if there was, you would still need the AspectJ compiler or a load-time weaving agent in order to make it work. Where is the benefit in using clunky annotation syntax, putting everything inside a string? IMO the native syntax is much more clear and elegant. If you want to use AspectJ, learn its syntax. ;-)